# Inserting Pop Functionality using link lists

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I'm new to data structures and started using C++ after a long time. After going through a few diagrams, I decided to create my own linked list (implementing a simple pop function).

Here is the code I came up with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    node *next;
}node;


node *start;
int count_1 = 0;


void push(int x)
{
    node *n = new node;
    node *temp;
    temp = n;
    temp->data = x;
    temp->next = start;
    start = temp;
    count_1++;
}

void ShowStack()
{
    for (int i=0; i<count_1; i++)
    {
        node *temp = start;
        cout<<temp->data<<endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}



int main()
{
    node *n = new node;
    start = n;


    n->data = 6;
    n->next = NULL;
    count_1++;

    ShowStack();

    push(7);
    push(8);
    push(9);
    push(20);

    //count_1=20;
    ShowStack();
    return 0;

}
```

It's very basic but I seem to be facing a problem; when I run the program the first output is '6' which is correct but after that, all the values are 20 (even if I hard-set the counter to some hard-coded value like 20 (see code). I'd appreciate if someone can explain what's wrong with this implementation (besides the fact that the program is very messy). Also, what steps would/should I take to get the correct 'pop' functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ShowStack() function, move "node *temp = start;" outside the loop.

Comment: This seems to the problem, yes!

Comment: Could you explain the working of the code as it is shown above?
Why was I getting a value of 20 every time? Like, if I set the counter to 20, it was full with value if 20 (except the first element).
And do you have an efficient algorithm/code for this problem?

Comment: Your ShowStack() is supposed to set temp=start outside the loop, then repeat count_1 times of {print what temp points to; move temp to the next node;}. But if you set temp=start inside the loop, you are going to print the stack head count_1 times.